# Unsupported query remaining error using layout parser library on mac m2

Tags: python, python-3.x, layout-parser

I am having a problem with using the layout parser library on my m2 mac mini. It keeps on giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/easystore/Pycharm/Study_GPT/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    model = lp.Detectron2LayoutModel('lp://PubLayNet/faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/config',
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Volumes/easystore/Pycharm/Study_GPT/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/layoutparser/models/detectron2/layoutmodel.py", line 119, in __init__
    self._create_model()
  File "/Volumes/easystore/Pycharm/Study_GPT/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/layoutparser/models/detectron2/layoutmodel.py", line 122, in _create_model
    self.model = detectron2.engine.DefaultPredictor(self.cfg)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Volumes/easystore/Pycharm/Study_GPT/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/detectron2/engine/defaults.py", line 288, in __init__
    checkpointer.load(cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS)
  File "/Volumes/easystore/Pycharm/Study_GPT/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/detectron2/checkpoint/detection_checkpoint.py", line 62, in load
    ret = super().load(path, *args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Volumes/easystore/Pycharm/Study_GPT/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fvcore/common/checkpoint.py", line 155, in load
    checkpoint = self._load_file(path)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Volumes/easystore/Pycharm/Study_GPT/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/detectron2/checkpoint/detection_checkpoint.py", line 108, in _load_file
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unsupported query remaining: f{'dl': ['1']}, orginal filename: /Users/.../.torch/iopath_cache/s/dgy9c10wykk4lq4/model_final.pth?dl=1
```

Can someone please help me fix this problem? It seems like a path issue but I am not sure.